# How to make a surface background half transparent in jetpack compose, but not the content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to achieve this layout:

[image]

In XML I would add an image in a relative layout with match_parent attributes, then a view with a black half-transparent background set to match_parent as well, then the content.

In compose I made this composeable:

```
@Composable
fun ImageCover(resourceId: Int, alpha: Float = 0.5f, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = resourceId),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Surface(
            color = Color.Black, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .alpha(alpha)
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is alpha is applied to the surface and its content. So no matter what I put in the content, even if it's another surface with a background, will also be half transparent. Here, for example, the two sentences and two components at the bottom will be half transparent as well.

Comment: can you use xml layout  for background?

Comment: @ВладимирКовальчук I can but then what's the point of compose? Isn't the whole point of compose to replace XML ?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The background color of the `Surface` is based on the `color` attribute.
Apply the **`alpha`** to the `color` property instead of the `Modifier`.

Something like:

```
   Surface(
        color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.6f), 
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ){ 
       //....
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What about if you have a fragment with a compose view and setContent. How would you make the fragment that holds the surface transparent?

Comment: @RichardDapice did you manage this? I need to do the same thing :) cant find a solution

Comment: @Coder123, I used a dialog fragment and changed some properties with the window manager.

dialog?.window?.attributes?.apply {
            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        }
        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gabriele Mariotti the same is in other controls.

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(
            color = Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
        ),
    text = "Text",
```